# How to get a I420 or RGB24 formatted Camera Stream in Windows?

Tags: windows, video, directshow

Camera optionally will display RGB24 and I420 video on some Windows machines, and will not do so on others machines. Actually, I've tested several cameras with this result.

I love BeatHarness, my cool old (no longer supported) audio visualizer software. It has served me (and my bands) faithfully for almost a decade. It's still kicking on some (un-networked) WinXP boxes at my practice spot.

Now, with some replacement machines (i.e., live use and such), the camera functions die. I've tested several otherwise functional USB cameras on several Windows machines. When BeatHarness indicates the cameras are YUY2 YUYV, the camera settings and preview are black or distorted. The I420 and RGB24 formats work like a charm.

It doesn't appear to be hardware specific, as the same camera that works on a Windows7 machine, doesn't work on my Windows10 laptop. A couple times, I think the same camera will work on one XP box and will not on another.

Some searching indicates it might have to do with DirectShow, but I'm not sure. And I've yet to find a comprehensible fix that I might test out. Maybe you have some ideas? Can I provide more info to make this question clearer?

Comment: I think it's a question for BeatHarness software (last updated in 2005!) to recognize video in those pixel formats correctly. Perhaps if you cannot find a physical camera with such pixel formats, maybe some of virtual camera software (sharing camera between apps etc) could do it for you. Overall this does not look like a programming question and hence voting for migration to SuperUser.

Comment: Thank you. Adding additional search terms from your response may have put me on the trail to a solution. In other forums (in some of which you are a participant), those with similar difficulties solved them using C++ (or its cousins). I wasn't certain or familiar enough to add it into the tags. Please forgive any imposition I may have caused here.